# do-while loop that either takes an int or a string?

Tags: java

When ever I run this the output is:

"Please input your name"
I enter it

"Please enter student number"
I enter it

"Please input the student name"

"please enter the student number"

```
String nameChoice = "";

do{

        System.out.println("Please input the students name");

        String name = s.nextLine();
        nameChoice = name;

        System.out.println("Please enter that students number");
        int studentNo = s.nextInt();



}while(!nameChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("done"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `s.nextInt()` reads only the integer entered and not the newline character after the entered integer. So you can add a `s.nextLine()` to read that newline character.

So do this:

```
int studentNo = s.nextInt();
s.nextLine();
```

If you are not doing this the next `nextLine()` method will be used to read the newline you entered.

Another method to avoid this problem is reading using `nextLine()` and parsing it to `integer`.

```
int studentNo = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
```